# redux form says component is readonly

Tags: redux, redux-form

i am getting an error using the redux form. It says my filename "search is only readable". Is this a redux form issue or some other problem? Does it have something to do with connect? For now I can only use the older way with forms

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
var Select = require('react-select');
import {fetchAllEmails, searchUsers} from '../actions/searchAction';
import {getDashBoardDataFromEmail, clearUserState} from '../actions/dashboardAction';
var LocalToken = localStorage.getItem('token');
import _ from 'lodash';
import {reduxForm} from 'redux-form';


const Search = React.createClass({

  contextTypes:{
    router: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
  },

  getInitialState: function(){
    return {
      value:'xyz'
    }
  },

  componentWillMount: function(){
    this.props.fetchAllEmails(LocalToken);

  },

  handleChange: function(e){
    this.props.getDashBoardDataFromEmail(LocalToken,e)
    this.context.router.push('/dashboard')
  },

  handleSearchChange(e) {
     this.setState({ value: e.target.value });
   },

   handleInputSubmit(){
     console.log('hello')
   },

  render(){
    const {fields: {someFormField, handleInputSubmit} }= this.props;

    return(
      <div>
        <h3 style={{textAlign:'center',color:'#b4b7c1'}}>Search</h3>

      <h6>Search for something</h6>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleInputSubmit}>
           <div>
             <input type="text" placeholder="Search By ..." {...someFormField} />
           </div>
        </form>
      </div>)
  }
})

Search = reduxForm({
  form:'Search',
  fields:['someFormField']
})(Search)


function mapStateToProps({ search,dashboardData,tokenValue }) {
  return {  search, dashboardData, tokenValue }
}

//functions from action
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){return bindActionCreators({fetchAllEmails, searchUsers, getDashBoardDataFromEmail, clearUserState},dispatch)}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Search);
```

Answer (score 8):

If you change
`const Search = React.createClass({`
to
`let Search = React.createClass({`
it will work.

Answer (score -2):

`redux-form` has nothing to do with whether your files are readable or not.

That's between you and your operating system.